# why when i'm upload image using carrierwave in rails 4 database is rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, strong-parameters

i try to save image file using carrierwave in rails 4, but when submit button is click database is rollback??? why ?

if i dont select image to upload and just send string only, all work properly but if i send image file i get error like this :

```
TypeError: can't cast ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to string: INSERT INTO "items" ("created_at", "description", "image", "name", "store_id", "sub_items", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
*** ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: TypeError: can't cast ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to string: INSERT INTO "items" ("created_at", "description", "image", "name", "store_id", "sub_items", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

my view :

```
<%= form_for @items, :url => dashboard_create_items_path(@store.id), :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, 'Name' %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
  <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
  <%= f.label :image, 'Image' %>
   <%= f.file_field :image %><br />
  <%= f.label :description, 'Description' %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %><br />
  <%= f.label :sub_items %><br>
  <%= f.select :sub_items, options_for_select([["true", true], ["false", false]]), :selected => 'true' %><br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

my controller :

```
def create_items    
    store = Store.find(params[:id])
    @items = store.items.create(item_params)

    if @items
      redirect_to dashboard_show_items_url(@items.id, store.id)
    else
      redirect_to dashboard_new_items_url
    end
  end

private

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :title, :image, :description, :sub_items, :store_id)
    end
```

please tell me when i'm wrong? thanks before

Comment: can we see your Item model? does it have `mount_uploader :images, ImageUploader`?

Comment: yes, i forget it xD
thanks @benjaminjosephw

Comment: Cool - posting this as an answer for people with similar problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may be seeing this error message because Carrierwave hasn't been initialized in your model.

The carrierwave method `mount_uploader` needs to be added to the image field in the model like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

(see the [docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#activerecord) for more details)