# Carrierwave NoMethodError: undefined method `image_url' for Item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

Please help. Two days installing Carrierwave, but stopped at errors:
 Showing /home/dima/rails_projects/my_store/app/views/items/show.html.erb where line #8 raised: **undefined method `image_url' for #**
items_controller.rb:

```
 def show
    unless @item 
      render text: "Page not here", status: 404
    end
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.create(item_params)
    if @item.errors.empty?
      redirect_to item_path(@item)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def update
    @item.update_attributes(item_params)
    if @item.errors.empty?
      redirect_to item_path(@item)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :price, :weight, :real, :image_attributes)
    end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= @item.name%></h1>
<ul>
    <li>Цена: <%= @item.price %> грн.</li>
   <li>Описание: <%= urls_to_links(urls_to_images(@item.description)) %></li>
   <li>Вес: <%= @item.weight %> кг</li>
   <li>Реальный: <%= @item.real %></li>
   <%= image_tag @item.image_url.to_s %>
 </ul>
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0, allow_nil: true } 
  validates :name, :description, presence: true

  #  has_one :image
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  # belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Create new item</h1>
<%= form_for @item, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: "form", locals: { f: f } %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Создать товар" %></p>
<% end %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<p>Наименоваие: <%= f.text_field :name %></p>
<p>Описание: <%= f.text_field :description %></p>
<p>Цена: <%= f.text_field :price %></p>
<p>Вес: <%= f.text_field :weight %></p>
<p>Реальный: <%= f.text_field :real %></p>
<label>My Image</label>
<p><%= f.file_field :image %></p>
```

Tried different variants (like withouts '#'). Please help in leaning Rails.
(Last time installed by screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads )

Upd: 
If I use

```
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :price, :weight, :real, :image)
    end
```

Have an error:
    TypeError: can't cast ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to string: INSERT INTO "items" ("created_at", "description", "image", "name", "price", "updated_at", "weight") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `has_one :image` is the reference from Item to Image, then to reference the image path you should use:

```
<%= image_tag @item.image.image.url if @item.image %>
```

instead of your current tag: <%= image_tag @item.image_url.to_s %>.

Additionally your form is written as if mount_uploader :image is defined on the Item model, but your model definition shows that it first has to go through the Image model to get the carrierwave image.  Perhaps just mount the image directly on item?

Comment: I received an error: 
    NoMethodError in Items#show
    Showing /home/dima/rails_projects/my_store/app/views/items/show.html.erb where line #8 raised:

    undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That is probably because item doesn't have an associated image model, that active record relationship is blank.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Have same error. Should I uncomment "belongs_to" and "has_one"?

Comment: Now image didn't save      Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at +0200
    Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"ans=", "item"=>{"name"=>"12121", "description"=>"212121", "price"=>"1212", "weight"=>"12", "real"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb6396dc0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/Rack20140317-14051-1pwswnp>, @original_filename="vim.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content- Disposition: form-data; name=\"item[image]\"; filename=\"vim.png\"\r\nContent-   Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Создать товар"}

Comment: Unpermitted parameters: image
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    SQL (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("created_at", "description", "name", "price", "updated_at", "weight") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 17 Mar 2014 21:31:59 UTC +00:00], ["description", "212121"], ["name", "12121"], ["price", 1212.0], ["updated_at", Mon, 17 Mar 2014 21:31:59 UTC +00:00], ["weight", 12.0]]
     (39.6ms)  commit transaction
     Redirected to http://localhost:3000/items/24

Comment: If has_one is commented out on Item then there is no way for an image to be stored with a Item?  Unless you mount the ImageUploader on Item.  Additionally to save a nested model (Image is nested on Item) you will need to use accepts_nested_attributes_for on Item.  Thats why I suggest mounting carrierwave on item directly.

Comment: Great Thanks! With your advices and this answers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962956/why-when-im-upload-image-using-carrierwave-in-rails-4-database-is-rollback I decided this problem!